# BASH - Run command using sudo but within a detached screen

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to run a command as a different user, but within a detached screen and can't seem to get the syntax quite right. If I split the commands I can get them to work, but when I piece them all together, nothing happens.

What I am trying:

```
COMMAND='COUNTER=0; while [ $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do echo Count: $COUNTER; let COUNTER=COUNTER+1; sleep 15; done'

if [ $USER_CURRENT = $USER_RUN_AS ]; then
    screen -dmS $REMOTE_REPO_NAME -c "$COMMAND 2>&1 >> $LOG_FILE_URI"        
 else

     # This works, but I would like it to run in detached screen
     # sudo su -s /bin/bash $USER_RUN_AS -c " $COMMAND 2>&1 >> $LOG_FILE_URI "

     # Tried piping screen to the sudo command
     # screen -dmS $REMOTE_REPO_NAME $COMMAND | sudo -S su -s /bin/bash $USER_RUN_AS 2>&1 >> $LOG_FILE_URI

     # Tried passing the command to screen
     screen -dmS $REMOTE_REPO_NAME -c "$COMMAND 2>&1 >> $LOG_FILE_URI | sudo -S su -s /bin/bash $USER_RUN_AS"

fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your second and third attempts have all the right pieces, but out of order.  Try

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash $USER_RUN_AS -c "screen -dmS $REMOTE_REPO_NAME \"$COMMAND 2>&1 >> $LOG_FILE_URI\" "
```

I don’t think it makes sense to be using a pipe.

Comment: I'm trying to run the command as another user within a screen.

Comment: @MikePurcell: Oops; my bad.  I’ve made another try.

Comment: This appears to work for me, but I'm not good enough with *nix to say with 100% certainty that it's always right. +1 anyways, sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
screen -dmS $REMOTE_REPO_NAME sudo su - $USER_RUN_AS -c "$COMMAND 2>&1 >> $LOG_FILE_URI"
```

is all you need. Just run sudo **within** your screen. 
**-c** switch to screen is "read config file". This is probably not what you want.

```
  -c file
        override  the default configuration file from "$HOME/.screenrc" to
        file.
```